# Can we use Favorite Tags for one-click searching in Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, tag-watching

Does the Android app allow access to the list of **Favorite Tags** with the ability to click on one of them (as it's done in *regular* SO)? I could not find a way to do it.

If there's none, could you please consider adding such feature?

Comment: consider adding ios-app too. I really wish this were implemented.

Comment: My related suggestion for the implementation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220693/favorite-views-searches-in-ios-app