# "Favorite" Views/Searches in iOS/Android App

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, android-app, ios-app

Related: [Restrict site specific views to specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220355/restrict-site-specific-views-to-specific-tags)

Most SO users, I'd imagine, keep a number of tabs open, jumping between all of them. Tabs in the app are likely a bad idea. I've got a proposal I think addresses the *problem* without forcing inappropriate paradigms.

Currently, you scroll to the top of the page to reveal the search bar. I propose hiding the search bar behind a search button to make room for three other buttons:

- **Favorites** store and recall favorite search/filter/sorts, organized by site. This is really the crux of the *tabs-alternative*
- **Filter** gives filtering options, such as featured, choice of questions-only or answers-only, unanswered, my tags, etc. Checkbox or radio for each.
- **Sort** after removing the options moved to Filter, is currently left with: Activity, Votes, Creation, Hot. The names should naturally match the desktop site: Active, Votes, Newest, and... wait what's *Hot* supposed to be?
- **Search** shows the text field we know and love.

---

### Two screenshots

First, a truly ugly mock-up of the bar formerly known as **search.**

[image]

---

Second, a not so ugly mock-up of the new **favorites** page:

[image]

---

I would rather use the app than the website, but the lack of quick access to the questions I *want* to see means I still leave a couple tabs open in the browser too, and spend more time there. I humbly feel **favorites** is the ideal solution.

Comment: I should add, I don't intend to propose introducing new search functionality in SE. Just to expose what's there more intuitively and with saved searches

Comment: +1 The ability to save searches would also resolve another [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223862/).

Comment: We have actually talked internally about both this and @cheapeffectivedietpills 's ideas a few months back. We have some mock-ups that we've thrown around about it, and I'll post a meta question soon for feedback on the our idea. The worry is that doing custom searches would be a *really* power-user feature rather than just a "mostly power-user feature".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Kasra. **Can't wait** to see your post! I agree this is the most "power-user" of all the feature requests I've made. I've made a few other suggestions ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682/dont-go-modal-in-the-app), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226906/filter-tag-list-to-my-favorites-in-app), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228526/show-me-more-questions-in-the-app-feed)) that are *all* trying to address the same usability problem. Maybe one of those strikes a chord :). I can discuss more in the iOS α chatroom if you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saved searches are now available in the beta channel for iOS8 users. (That save button is an iOS8 feature.  I will probably add an accessory button for 7.)

[image: saved searches]

Comment: It's so intuitive! I have no words...

Comment: Does the android app have something like that?