# Filter tag list to my favorites in app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, ios-app

Can we add a My Favorites option to the tag sort/filter list in the iOS app?

[image]

Comment: I had considered adding favorites editing to this feature request, but as written it is only for seeing my tags so I have easy access to those questions. Currently I either type it manually, or find a tagged question and tap its tag.

Comment: I'll see what we can do about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys verified a feature request without me!  I don't think that's how it's supposed to work. ;-)

Fortunately, this was a relatively simple thing to implement.  The next version of the API has an endpoint for this, so I just needed to wire that up to the sorting mechanism in our tag search controller.

This was fixed in 0.1.4something, but I forgot to come back and tag [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: I was only doing your job for you. Isn't that how it's supposed to work? ;)

Comment: Clearly, I'm doing it wrong.  Moar testerz!

Comment: It seems like you got a big influx of moar testerz recently. It's a popular tag these days!

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to see [a bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229974/sorting-by-favorite-tag-crashes) about this feature since I didn't realize it even existed yet. (I couldn't reproduce the bug; it's working great for me)

That said, the feature request side sure looks to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of version 0.1.50:

[image]