# Sorting by favorite tag crashes

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue

1. Open sliding menu
2. Go to stack overflow
3. Select Tags tab
4. Press the double arrow for sorting
5. Select favorite
6. Crashes

Using iPhone 5s, iOS 7.0.6

EDIT:
Crash log
Incident Identifier: 6E67EDAE-D241-43A8-BE5C-E0BD61F8214D
CrashReporter Key:   e9aa51443d7fe66696d88d7ae9917c5eea0c2b4d
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:             Stack Exchange [2825]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/127D0433-CFD8-40DF-BDD0-5FED99217E33/Stack Exchange.app/Stack Exchange
Identifier:          com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod
Version:             0.1.50 (0.1.50)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-04-18 14:52:11.257 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.6 (11B651)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1868d709c 0x192855d78 0x1868dbd14 0x1868d9a7c 0x1867f94ac 0x18741d9cc 0x18738caa0 0x100261948 0x100261b98 0x100262a68 0x10026039c 0x18738be04 0x187378d38 0x18743ad7c 0x192e243e0 0x192e29930 0x192e243e0 0x192e2b3fc 0x192e2b638 0x192fb9918 0x192fb97a8)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   QuartzCore                      0x00000001893a1e68 0x189394000 + 56936
1   QuartzCore                      0x00000001893a7c7c 0x189394000 + 81020
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001867d1f38 0x1867cc000 + 24376
3   QuartzCore                      0x00000001893aa6e0 0x189394000 + 91872
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192e243dc 0x192e20000 + 17372
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192e27568 0x192e20000 + 30056
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186896d60 0x1867cc000 + 830816
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001868950a0 0x1867cc000 + 823456
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001867d5b34 0x1867cc000 + 39732
9   GraphicsServices                0x000000018c1fb82c 0x18c1f0000 + 47148
10  UIKit                           0x00000001898140e4 0x189798000 + 508132
11  Stack Exchange                  0x00000001000933c8 0x100060000 + 209864
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000192e3fa9c 0x192e3c000 + 15004

Comment: I had no idea favorite tags were even implemented. Last I heard it was status-planned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226906/filter-tag-list-to-my-favorites-in-app. That said, it seems to be working for me

Comment: Do you possibly have no favorite tags?

Comment: What's the deal with the down vote for reporting a bug? Who down voted this? If you don't want bug reports then don't ask me to report them.

Comment: Yes I have three favorite tags on stackoverflow.

Comment: Wasn't me. I'll balance out with an upvote. You're clearly getting a crash, and going above and beyond with your error reporting.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We have seen your crash report in our system and fixed this in version **0.1.55**.